# How do I print line above a specific word in line?

Tags: python, ubuntu

basically i have a text file like the below:

```
- Brandon = 1
- Mark = 70
- Charlie = 2
- Mark = 65
- Jon = 3
- Mark = 73
- May = 4
- Mark = 88
- Nathan = 5
- Mark = 95
- etc..
```

Now I want a program to read all lines of the text file, (which I know how to do) and check the value of the mark and if it is higher than 70, it will print the mark and also the line above it (which is the line of the name of the student). Does anyone know how this is done because i don't have a clue. Thank you for your help!

Regards,
Joe

Comment: Aren't the name and marks on the same line?

Comment: "... (which I know how to do) ...". Prove it.

Comment: with open ("bla/bla/bla") as f: ..... f.readlines() ...... if line = mark: .. this is what I have so far

Comment: @joe we need to see the code you tried, that won't do it. Put it in the question formatted properly

Comment: all i've tried is in the line above, i'm pretty new to python and i have no clue how to continue :/

Comment: `how to open file in python`, `how to read file in python`, `how to loop in python`, `how to print in python`, `how to compare numbers in python` these are good keywords to start searching on [Google](http://www.google.com)

Comment: i found the next.() function which prints the next line after a specific line from a text file.. is there something similar but instead prints the line before?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to go about it, although I am not going to explain how any of it works. You will need to study up on `regex`, `list comprehensions`, the `enumerate` built in method and more.

```
import re

with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    lines = [l.strip() for l in lines] # list comprehension
    for index, line in enumerate(lines):
        mark = re.search(r'\d+',line) # regex
        if int(mark.group()) > 70:
            print ('Mark: ', mark.group())
            print ('Line above:', lines[index-1])
```

NOTE: you will need to remove the last line in your text file that contains "- etc..." for this code to work. Also, every line in the text file has to have a mark (score) in it. And no empty lines either :)
Should you txt file change and the mark on the first line is > 70, then the 'line above' would actually be the last line in the file - at least in this code.

Comment: this returns attribute error on group. NoneType object has no attribute  'group'... but many thanks for your time.

Comment: hat is probably because "etc" is the last line of your text file. Remove "etc" and it will work fine. Also make sure that the last line is not an empty line either. As long as every line in file has a person = number it will work. However, what you going to do if the first line in your text file has a mar above 70, there is no line before it to print? In the case of the code, if the first line of txt file has a mar > 70, then the last line of the txt file will print.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here and see if you can understand what this piece of code is doing. It's well commented.

```
#opening a file
path_to_file = '/usr/home/file.txt'

#reading file
#saving lines to a list
with open(path_to_file, "r") as f:
    l1.readllines(f)

#produced list
l1 = ['- Brandon = 1', '- Mark = 70', '- Charlie = 2', '- Mark = 65', '- Jon = 3',
      '- Mark = 73', '- May = 4', '- Mark = 88', '- Nathan = 5', '- Mark = 95']


#counter to check and get the previous line  
counter = 0

#iterate over list    
for i in l1:

    #define what score is, and save it as int
    score = int(i.split("=")[1])

    #conditional check
    if score > 70:
        #if condition is true, then print previous line
        print l1[counter-1]

    #autoincrement
    counter += 1
```

Produced Output:

```
- Jon = 3
- May = 4
- Nathan = 5
```

If you change `print l1[counter-1]` to `print l1[counter]` **or** `print i` you'll get the following output:

```
- Mark = 73
- Mark = 88
- Mark = 95
```

As stated by @taesu, you should search for sentences like:

- how to open file in python
- how to read file in python
- how to loop in python
- how to print in python

because this is the required workflow for your task.

- open a file
- read lines
- for each line, check if condition is true
- if condition is true, then
- do something

easy as py.

Comment: how exactly is the list produced? do I have to write all the file content into a list? Thanks in advance